# Choosing BizTalk Custom Pipeline Component Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I need to create a new custom pipeline component for BizTalk 2013. As far as I know, the excellent Pipeline Component Wizard does't work with VS2012 so I'm having to hand code all the boiler plate stuff.

I have built the custom component and deployed to the gac along with all dependencies.

I am getting the common yet miss-leading error message:

*You have selected an invalid pipeline component assembly. Please check security settings for the assembly if you are loading it from an UNC path*

My class begins as follows:

```
 public class UpsSupersededRecordRemover : Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IComponent, IBaseComponent, IPersistPropertyBag, IComponentUI
{

    private System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceManager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("BizTalkers.PipelineComponents.UpsSupersededRecordRemover", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

I have created a .resx resource file called UpsSupersededRecordRemover.resx. 
When I use Reflector to view the component assembly I can see the resx file is nicely contained within:

[image]

So I have checked for the usual causes of this error: public class, correct ref to the resource file, dependencies gac'd.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong or suggest what else I can do to get a better error message?

Comment: Have you tried using the Pipeline Wizard in an earlier version of Visual Studio and then opened the solution in VS2012 letting it upgrade it and compare it to your hand coded one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the source for the Pipeline Component Wizard and upgrade the project to VS 2012 (I actually haven't tried with VS 2012 but we did have to do this in the 2006-2009 era.
2. Create you Pipeline Component Project in Visual Studio 2010 then add/upgrade the project to you VS 2012 Solution.

All of the BizTalk Interfaces are identical to previous versions so the VS 2010/2012 difference is perfunctory.

Comment: Both of your suggestions sound good although I think they are hoops that shouldn't need to be jumped through. It's a shame Microsoft haven't managed to include the functionality of the wizard into BizTalk.